# vpn client of cellphone hotspot cannot be accessed and cannot set to static ip

Tags: vpn, pptp

So the network is: I have an Asus router as a PPTP VPN server in the company, and I have a win10 laptop at home as a PPTP VPN client with an android phone hotspot. I have no problem making the VPN connection on my laptop and ping/access the router with its virtual VPN address and its LAN address, I can also ping/access the LAN address of the pc under that router.

The problem is that:
I cannot set win10 as a static virtual VPN address, when I try it I will fail the VPN connection. Is there a way to set a static virtual VPN address instead of assigning it from the VPN server?
I cannot ping/access from the router or the pc under the router to the LAN address (always 192.168.43.x for the android hotspot) of my laptop at home. I do can ping/access from the router or the pc under the router to the virtual VPN address of my laptop. What should I configure?

Thank you.

Comment: Its worth asking why you are using PPTP?   The PPTP protocol was broken a LONG time ago - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45509/are-there-any-known-vulnerabilities-in-pptp-vpns-when-configured-properly

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to vpn so I dont know that PPTP is broken and I will change to OpenVPN in the future but for now I just want to solve current problems.